# ¿Cómo actualizar mi sitio web luego de subir una imagen?

Tags: jsp, eclipse, aplicación-web, servlets

¡Hola! Estoy teniendo problemas en la subida de una imagen vía servlet a mi sitio web; utilizo eclipse y jsp. En teoría, todo el proceso se realiza correctamente, la ruta de la  imagen se guarda bien en mi base de datos (utilizo Postgres como gestor) y la imagen se guarda y actualiza correctamente en mi proyecto (La imagen me sale en la carpeta adecuada del proyecto), pero, si vuelvo a donde la imagen debería de aparecer, esta no carga por alguna razón, tengo que volver a correr mi proyecto para que esta aparezca, pero sin hacer un refresh ni nada por el estilo, ¿alguna idea de por qué pasa esto?

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda, un saludo.

En base a un comentario, dejaré los extractos de código que considero importantes:

Primero, el formulario:

```
<form class="form" name="Frm-foto" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SL_subir_foto_banner" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table class="table table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="datatable-1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                            <b>Estimado usuario, por favor atienda las siguientes recomendaciones para subir su foto:</b>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <p>Foto de orientación horizontal.</p>
                                <p>Formato y dimensiones: el formato debe ser jpg, la foto debe de ser 1900 x 600 px para que se adecúe al tamaño del banner.</p>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                            <div class="cuadro-fotoNima" align="center">
                                <img id="preview" src="../../img/slides/nivo/foto-banner1.jpg" name="preview"  alt="Foto"
                                style="width: 1000px; height: 350px; border-bottom-color: white; margin: 2px;" />
                            </div> &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto"
                            onchange="Test.UpdatePreview(this)" required="required">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input class="action" type="submit" value="Subir imagen"/>
        </form>
```

Luego, el servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        DT_publicaciones dtpub = new DT_publicaciones();
        Tbl_publicaciones tpub = new Tbl_publicaciones();
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        File fichero = null;
        File fichero2 = null;

        String rutaFichero = null;

        for(FileItem item : items)
        {
            FileItem uploaded = item;
            if(!uploaded.isFormField())
            {
                /////////TAMAÑO DEL ARCHIVO ////////
                long size = uploaded.getSize();

                /////// GUARDAMOS EN UN ARREGLO LOS FORMATOS QUE SE DESEAN PERMITIR
                List<String> formatos = Arrays.asList("image/jpeg");

                ////// COMPROBAR SI EL TAMAÑO Y FORMATO SON PERMITIDOS //////////
                if(formatos.contains(uploaded.getContentType()))
                {

                    int contador = dtpub.obtenerMenuOrder();
                    rutaFichero = "foto-banner"+contador+".jpg";
                    path = "C:\\Users\\pc\\git\\PortalWebHNMN\\PortalHNMN\\WebContent\\img\\slides\\nivo\\";
                    String url2 = path.substring(52);
                    url2 = url2.replace("\\", "/");

                    fichero = new File(path+rutaFichero);

                    ///////// GUARDAR EN EL SERVIDOR //////////////
                    uploaded.write(fichero);

                    /////// ACTUALIZAMOS EL CAMPO URLFOTO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
                    String url = url2+rutaFichero;
                    tpub.setPublic_titulo(url);
                    if(dtpub.guardarBanner(tpub))
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/CMS/menu/editBanner.jsp?msj=1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/CMS/menu/editBanner.jsp?msj=2");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("SERVIDOR: VERIFIQUE QUE EL ARCHIVO CUMPLA CON LAS ESPECIFICACIONES REQUERIDAS!!!");
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+ "/CMS/menu/editBanner.jsp?msj=3");                      
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("SERVLET: ERROR AL SUBIR LA FOTO: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Cabe recalcar, como mencioné antes, que el proceso de subir la imagen, en teoría, se hace correctamente, pero no sé si hay alguna función que estoy obviando para provocar el recargado, o algo por el estilo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos. No creo que puedas recibir respuestas acertadas sin conocer el caso en detalle. Sería de mucha ayuda si puedes poner algo de código para intentar entender el problema.